# PHP/MySQL variable in URL - text being stripped out and numerical part only used in selecting database records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL select statement which is intended to select data from a MySQL database when it matches the variable value entered in the URL, so if `?id=12` is appended to the URL it should return the database row where `id` equals 12.

When I was trying to break the script by entering odd values in the URL, I came across this weird problem: if a user enters a number followed by some text in the URL, it matches the numerical part of the string entered in the URL, e.g.:

```
...index.php?id=12agsgs
```

will match the record where `id = 12`, which is not intended.

If the text appears before the number, an error or empty result is returned, as expected:

```
...index.php?id=agsgs12
```

gives empty or error.

Everything is very simple; the code to `GET` the variable is:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $dbConnect->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
}
```

The SQL select code is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` = '$id'" ;
```

The field `id` in `tablename` is an auto-incrementing integer index field. So entering `.../index.php?id=12agsgs` should return an empty result.

Have I missed something really obvious? This seems quite weird and I can't get my head around what's happening. Any help will be much appreciated as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's MySQL "helpfully" converting `12agsgs` to a number for you (and coming up with 12), because it knows the `id` column is numeric. You can make it stop by doing a `BINARY` comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE BINARY `id` = '$id'
```

Comment: Excellent - problem solved in a sec. It WAS, if not obvious, at least my fault and pretty elementary.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL converts strings to numbers when one of the operands is a number. It's called [type conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html) and is covered in the manual.

You can see this in practice in this simple [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/056432/1)

Comment: Thanks, Andreas - both answers excellent but as Ed gave the code I've marked his as accepted.